# How to load jquery cookie library for anonymous user

Tags: 8, javascript

It seems  with login user jQuery Cookie added and worked correctly but when I visit my website with not login user(anonymous) then  I faced with `TypeError: $.cookie is not a function`. Why This happened and **how can I attach jQuery cookie libraries for not logged in users by default?**

Notes: 
My theme is based on Drupal Bootstrap theme

Comment: By default no libraries are attached, like in D7 so in your theme or module you have to define library that depends on jquery and/or the cookie library and attach it.

Comment: in drupal 7 I got jquery.cookie.js file and put it in theme file and in theme.info add it.
but it seems it exists here and it is not require I download and add it like drupal 7, is this right? tell me what is the solution for this ?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/assets

Comment: @IvanJaros you mean I have to manually add it to my theme?

Comment: @IvanJaros can you provide some snippet as answer for this question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For available Jquery and Jquery cookie for anonymous user, it should add it on  theme libraries dependencies , as example if your theme name is `themename`  on `themename.libraries.yml` add

in Drupal 8

```
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery.cookie
```

(Drupal 9 Deprecated core/jquery.cookie and will remove in D10.)

**then in Drupal 9 and 10 use**

```
  dependencies:
    - core/js-cookie
```

Thanks @Mr.Thi to mention this

Comment: Drupal 9 Deprecated core/jquery.cookie and will remove in D10. use core/js-cookie instead. https://www.drupal.org/node/3104677